# netty ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter cuts frame at ~1500 bytes

Tags: java, web-services, netty

I have implemented a server application which reads incoming bytes with a ChannelInblundHandlerAdapter using the netty framework.

My problem as shown in the title is, that i irregularly get content from the client which, I think so, is cut after ~1.500 bytes. For example: In such case I should receive a large JSON array. Because it is cut I cannot parse it.

I have tried to Decode the message with an additional ByteToMessageDecoder channel in the pipeline before consuming it. But that don't solves the issue. I have no Delimiter within the JSON i could check for and stick the two (or more) parts together again.

Here's my pipeline config:

```
        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
        b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
                        ch.pipeline().addLast(new IdleStateHandler(45,0,0));
                        ch.pipeline().addLast(new MyByteToMessageDecoder());
                        ch.pipeline().addLast(new GatewayCommunicationHandler());
                    }
                })
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_RCVBUF, 8192)
                .childOption(ChannelOption.RCVBUF_ALLOCATOR, new FixedRecvByteBufAllocator(8192))
                .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

        initRestServer();

        // Bind and start to accept incoming connections.
        ChannelFuture f = b.bind(Config.gatewayPort).sync();
        f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
```

And thats my ByteToMessageDecoder: (I know its a mess, but I had no idea how to handle with it in my case)

```
public class MyByteToMessageDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder {

@Override
protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) {
    byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[in.readableBytes()];
    in.getBytes(in.readerIndex(), receivedBytes);


    if (receivedBytes[in.readableBytes()-1] != (byte) 0) {
        out.add(receivedBytes);
        return;
    }

    int lenForOutBytes = 0;
    for (Object o : out) {
        byte[] bytes = (byte[]) o;
        lenForOutBytes += bytes.length;
    }

    byte[] outBytes = new byte[lenForOutBytes];

    for (Object o : out) {
        byte[] bytes = (byte[]) o;

        if (out.size() == 1) {
            outBytes = (byte[]) out.get(0);
        }
        else {
            int i = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
                outBytes[i + j] = bytes[j];
            }
            i += bytes.length;
        }
    }

    ctx.fireChannelRead(outBytes);
    in.resetReaderIndex();
}
...
```

Does anyone else have such a problem.

Thanks for your replies

Br Joe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have seen that this issue happens frequently, so I'm purposely a bit broader than I usually do

This issue happens because TCP is stream based, and not packet based.

This basically happens:

1. [client] Wants to send 10k bytes of data
2. [client] Sends the data to the TCP layer
3. [client] The TCP layer splits up the packets, it knows the max packet size is 1500 (thats the default MTU *almost all* networks use)
4. [client] The client sends packets to the server containing 40 bytes as headers, and 1460 bytes as data
5. [server] Netty receives the first packet of data, and directly calls you function, the first packet contains 1460 bytes of data
6. [server] In the time that your function needed to progress the remaining data (initial data - 1260)

So solve this problems, there are multiple ways

## Prepending messages with lengths:

While this is generally the easiest method to solve packets, it's also the least efficient one when dealing with small and large messages at the same time. This also requires a protocol change.

The basic idea is that you prepend the length before you send the packet, and that allows you to properly split the messages

### Advantages

- No need to loop over the data to filter out characters, or block forbidden characters
- If you have relay system in your network, they don't have to do any hard parsing for the message boundaries

### Disadvantages

- The length of the message has to known in advantage, in long messages, this is memory expansive

### How?

If you use a standard integer field, this is really simple to do as Netty has build in classes for this:

- [`LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.html)
- [`LengthFieldPrepender`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/LengthFieldPrepender.html)

This is used in the following manner inside your pipeline

```
// int maxFrameLength, int lengthFieldOffset, int lengthFieldLength, int lengthAdjustment, int initialBytesToStrip
pipeline.addLast(new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(1024 * 4, 0, 2, 0, 2));
// int lengthFieldLength, int lengthAdjustment
pipeline.addLast(new LengthFieldPrepender(2, 0));
```

This basically frames the packets like the following:

You send:

```
DATA: 12B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 57 6f 72 6c 64 21             |Hello World!    |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

[`LengthFieldPrepender`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/LengthFieldPrepender.html) converts this to:

```
DATA: 14B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 00 0c 48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 57 6f 72 6c 64 21       |..Hello World!  |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

Then when you receive message, [`LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.html) decodes this to:

```
DATA: 12B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 57 6f 72 6c 64 21             |Hello World!    |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

---

## Splitting messages on simple delimiters

Some protocols take on a different approach, instead of splitting on a fixes length, they split on a delimiter. A quick way to see is that strings in Java end at a `"`, lines in a text file end at newlines, paragraphs in natural text end at double newlines.

### Advantages

- Relatively easy to produce if you know a certain data doesn't contain characters, JSON for example usually does not contain spaces, so separating out messages by a space is easy.
- Easy to implement from scripting languages, as no state is needed

### Disadvantages

- Conflicts with the framing character may bloat the message size
- Length is not known in advance, so either set hard coded limit in code, or keep on reading till out of memory or the end of data
- Requires reading of every character even if you are not interested in the packet

### How?

When sending messages from Netty, you need to manually add your delimiter to the messages themselves, when receiving you can use a [`DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder`](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder.html) to decode the incoming stream into messages.

Example pipeline:

This is used in the following manner inside your pipeline

```
// int maxFrameLength, ByteBuf... delimiters
pipeline.addLast(1024 * 4, DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
```

When sending messages, you need to add you delimiter manually:

```
DATA: 14B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 57 6f 72 6c 64 21 0d 0a       |Hello World!..  |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

When receiving messages, [`DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder`](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder.html) converts the messages into frames for you:

```
DATA: 12B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 57 6f 72 6c 64 21             |Hello World!    |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

---

## Splitting on complex business delimiters

Not all framing is easy, and some solutions are actually the best if avoided, but sometimes, you really need to do some dirty work.

### Advantages

- Can virtually handle all existing data structures
- No protocol modifications needed

### Disadvantages

- Usually you have to inspect every byte
- Code can be hard to follow
- Quick solutions can give weird bugs with input that it thinks is malformatted

This falls under 2 categories:

- Existing decoder based
- Pattern detection

### Existing decoder based

With these solutions, you basically use existing decoders from other frameworks to parse you packets, and detect failures in their handling.

Example with [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) and [`ReplayingDecoder`](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/ReplayingDecoder.html):

```
public class GSONDecoder
    extends ReplayingDecoder<Void> {

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf buf, List<Object> out) 
        throws Exception {

        out.add(gson.fromJson(new ByteBufInputStream(buf, false), Object.class));
    }
}
```

### Pattern detection

If you are going to use the pattern detection approach, you need to understand your protocol. Let's make a pattern detection decoder for JSON.

Based on the structure of JSON, let's make the following assumptions:

1. JSON is based on matching pairs of `{` and `}`, and `[` and `]`
2. Matching pairs of `{` and `}` should be ignored between `"`
3. `"` should be ignored when prepended by a `\`
4. A `\` should be ignored if prepended by a `\`, when parsed from the left to right

Based on these properties, lets make an [`ByteToMessageDecoder`](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/ByteToMessageDecoder.html) based on these assumptions:

```
public static class JSONDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder {

    // Notice, this class is designed for JSON without a charset definition at the start, adding this is hard as we basicly have to call differend
    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
        in.markReaderIndex();

        int fromIndex = in.readerIndex();

        int unclosedCurlyBracketsSeen = 0;
        boolean inQuotedSection = false;
        boolean nonWhitespaceSeen = false;
        boolean slashSeen = false;

        while (in.isReadable()) {
            boolean newSlashSeenState = false;
            byte character = in.readByte();
            if (character == '{' && !inQuotedSection) {
                unclosedCurlyBracketsSeen++;
            }
            if (character == '}' && !inQuotedSection) {
                unclosedCurlyBracketsSeen--;
            }
            if (character == '[' && !inQuotedSection) {
                unclosedCurlyBracketsSeen++;
            }
            if (character == ']' && !inQuotedSection) {
                unclosedCurlyBracketsSeen--;
            }
            if (character == '"' && !slashSeen) {
                inQuotedSection = !inQuotedSection;
            }
            if (character == '\\' && !slashSeen) {
                newSlashSeenState = true;
            }
            if (!Character.isWhitespace(character)) {
                nonWhitespaceSeen = true;
            }
            slashSeen = newSlashSeenState;
            if(unclosedCurlyBracketsSeen == 0 && nonWhitespaceSeen) {
                int targetIndex = in.readerIndex();
                out.add(in.slice(fromIndex, targetIndex - fromIndex).retain());
                return;
            }
        }

        // End of stream reached, but our JSON is not complete, reset our progress!
        in.resetReaderIndex();
    }

}
```

When receiving messages, this is how it works:

```
DATA: 35B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 7b 22 68 69 21 22 2c 22 53 74 72 69 6e 67 3a 20 |{"hi!","String: |
|00000010| 5c 22 48 69 5c 22 22 7d 20 20 7b 22 73 6c 61 73 |\"Hi\""}  {"slas|
|00000020| 68 22 3a                                        |h":             |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+

DATA: 34B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 22 5c 5c 22 7d 7b 22 4e 65 73 74 65 64 3a 22 3a |"\\"}{"Nested:":|
|00000010| 7b 22 64 65 65 70 65 72 22 3a 7b 22 6f 6b 22 7d |{"deeper":{"ok"}|
|00000020| 7d 7d                                           |}}              |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

As you can see, we received 2 messages, where 1 was even fragmented between 2 "virtual TCP" packets, this is converted by our "JSON decoder" to the following ByteBuf packets:

```
DATA: 24B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 7b 22 68 69 21 22 2c 22 53 74 72 69 6e 67 3a 20 |{"hi!","String: |
|00000010| 5c 22 48 69 5c 22 22 7d                         |\"Hi\""}        |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+

DATA: 16B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 20 20 7b 22 73 6c 61 73 68 22 3a 22 5c 5c 22 7d |  {"slash":"\\"}|
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+

DATA: 29B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 7b 22 4e 65 73 74 65 64 3a 22 3a 7b 22 64 65 65 |{"Nested:":{"dee|
|00000010| 70 65 72 22 3a 7b 22 6f 6b 22 7d 7d 7d          |per":{"ok"}}}   |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the great explanations. I really appreciate that. Even if it doesn't solve all my problems, because I have to handle with more than JSON responses/requests. I will let the issue open for another few days. Even if I want to mark it as solved because of the quality of your answer.

Comment: You might be able to use the "Existing decoder based" solution, this is based on the aspect of `ReplayingDecoder` that it automatically ignores packets that are too short because a build in error system. but this means that you decode method may keep getting called till there is a packet large enough, so it should have no side-effects